# Find the volume of a body formed by a cylinder and a hyperboloid

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates, iterated-integrals

Find the volume of a body formed by a cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ and a hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 + 9 = z^2$

**My solution**

Let's try to build the body data
[image]

When viewed from above, it will look like a circle with a radius of 3 and a center at the point $x = 0, y = 0$. The volume will be the same at the top and bottom due to symmetry, so we can only consider the part where $0 \leq z$.
Let's move on to cylindrical coordinates using the replacement: $x = r\cos(\phi), y = r\sin(\phi), z = z$. Let's find the limits of integration.
$$0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$$
$$0 \leq r \leq 3$$
A $z$ will be bounded from above by a hyperboloid $x^2 + y^2 + 9 = z^2$
$$r^2\cos^2(\phi) + r^2\sin^2(\phi) + 9 = z^2$$
$$r^2 + 9 = z^2$$
at the very beginning we chose the part where $0 \leq z$, therefore
$$\sqrt{r^2 + 9} = z$$
As a result, we obtain the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{3}rdr\int_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2 + 9}}dz$$

And it needs to be counted. Please tell me if I did all this correctly? And at the end you will need to multiply by 2 to get the volume of the upper and lower parts

Comment: Note that the first and third integral are trivial, so the problem reduces to calculating the volume using the shell method; $$2\pi\int_0^3 r(2\sqrt{r^2+9})dr$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve for $z$, not for $z^2$, therefore I believe it should be $z=\sqrt{9+r^{2}}.$ Rest I believe is alright.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, I made a mistake in setting the limit for $z$, because I wrote it down for $z^2$

Comment: DM me , vuk.stojiljkovic999@gmail.com I wrote a nice problem book for analysis 2(which contains also vector analysis), there are many problems solved in great detail with pictures.